# Dependent Probability Distribution and Density Function

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Find the distribution function and density function of $Y = \sin X,$ where $X$ is distributed uniformly between $0$ and $\pi.$

Edit:
I know that the function is increasing from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and decreasing from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ and have hence split the function into two parts:

$P(Y\le \sin^{-1}(y)) = 2\frac{\sin^{-1}(y)}{\pi},$ for $(0,\pi/2)$

$P(Y\le \sin^{-1}(y)) = 1-2\frac{\sin^{-1}(y)-\pi/2}{\pi},$ for $(\pi/2,\pi).$

But, on evaluation, the solution turns out to be 2 which is clearly wrong.
Would appreciate some help.

Edit(2): Okay, I now understand that for $(0,\pi)$ $Y=\sin(x)$ has a solution at $x=\sin^{-1}(y)$ and $\pi-\sin^{-1}(y)$ and thus has a solution of $2\frac{\sin^{-1}(y)}{\pi}$.

Now for $(\pi,2\pi)$ if the solution same at $\pi+\sin^{-1}(y)$ and $2\pi-\sin^{-1}(y)$, then I get the solution as 
$\frac{\sin^{-1}(y)-\pi}{\sin^{-1}(y)}$.

Am i right? And if so, to get the final solution should I just add these two solutions?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have tried to improve the TeX code in your edit. (And up-voted to cancel the previous down-vote.) You seem to be making some progress. Maybe the clues in my 'Answer' will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clues so you can check your answer when you get it: The support of the distribution of $Y$ is $(−1,1).$ The density function is symmetrical about $0$ and has vertical asymptotes at $−1$ and $1$.

The random variable $W = (Y + 1)/2 \sim Beta(.5,.5),$ illustrated on Wikipedia (and sometimes called the 'bathtub' distribution).

The transformation is not single-valued, so I suggest you do one
quadrant at a time.

Simulation in R:

```
 y = sin(runif(10^6, 0, 2*pi))
 hist(y, br=50, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

Comment: When you finish, you might want to google 'arcsine law' to see that this distribution and its relatives have many interesting applications in probability modeling. Your problem is not just a drill exercise.

Comment: Sure, Thanks so much. The arcsine law was an interesting read.